# Asus N56J locked bios prevents me from installing ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi, windows-10, secure-boot

Ive been trying to install ubuntu on my laptop for hours via disabling the secure boot option in bios with out success. Ive been getting the error 0xc000007b time and time again.

ive tried the shift + restart thing. the disable secure-boot is still greyed.

Can you guys help me with a workaround, I really want to move away from windows and move in to linux.

Ive been searching like crazy but come up short, if this is the wrong way please point me in the right direction.

Regards